# SQLite query with 2 conditions on 2 columns

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi is there posibility to construct SQLite query like this
`SELECT * FROM master WHERE (age=1 OR age=4) AND WHERE city LIKE '%Bo%'`

Is a correct version of this query or queries on 2 columns are imposible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. However you can only use the keyword `WHERE` once, simply combine you conditions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM master WHERE (age=1 OR age=4) AND city LIKE '%Bo%'
```